# Angular 6 : Code getting obfuscated while serving the app. Is this expected?

Tags: angular, ng-build

http://localhost:4200/#/home

Hi!

I am trying to serve my app using **ng serve --open**.

I am now getting the **#** appended to the *localhost:4200*, because of this, I am not able to see my code while debugging the source code using breakpoints.

I am believing that the code is being obfuscated, as shown in the attached image: [image]

Here, I am able to stop at breakpoints, but code is not clear.

So, I am not sure why this **#** is being appended recently.

Any pointers on how to get rid of this.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your CLI version? Do you have an accurate basehref or a custom deployurl? Do you get the same issue when debugging in chrome?

Comment: Angular CLI - **v6.1.5**.

--- base href is default : **`<base href="/">`**

--- **Yes**, I get the same issue in chrome as well.

--- Thanks.

Comment: Do you have something set up to serve as aot? Like if you did `ng serve --aot=false` to serve as jit is it the same?

Comment: Sorry, I have no set up to serve as *aot* . Yesterday, I have tried to deploy the app and ran the command **`ng build --prod`**. May be because of this *--prod* tag, it is causing this behavior ?

Comment: prod would build as aot by default but it depends if you're debugging against a prod build dist or just what ng serve is serving? I've personally not ran into this issue, the # you see shouldn't make a difference.